# Getting exception on switching from android activity to react activity

Tags: android, react-native

I am new to react-native.
We are integrating the react native source code into an existing android project. 
We are following the below tutorial :
https://medium.com/mindorks/react-native-integration-with-existing-app-f2757c2e672d

After adding the required react-native classes and following all steps, we are facing some crash issues when we are switching android activity to react-native activity.

Here is the crash issue

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Method 'void
>   androidx.core.net.ConnectivityManagerCompat.()' is inaccessible
>   to class 'com.facebook.react.modules.netinfo.NetInfoModule'
>   (declaration of 'com.facebook.react.modules.netinfo.NetInfoModule'
>   appears in /data/app/com.ttl.reactintegrationdemo-2/base.apk)